# Get a specific section of the a given menu

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, menu

in drupal 6, i've been experimenting with `menu_tree('menu-name');` but i can't seem to figure out a way to get only a certain section of the tree, say the 3rd tier from the root... one tier deep.

i don't want to use another module, and would be prefer to use drupal api.

as always, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no proper core function for this in Drupal 6. You can check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841961/drupal-menu-system-outputting-a-tree-one-level-down/1842859#1842859) for a workaround from code, but even if you don't want to use another module, you should check [jhedstroms answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841961/drupal-menu-system-outputting-a-tree-one-level-down/1843965#1843965) as well.